# Modeling database with many (0,n) relations

Tags: sql, database

I have a database to manage characters and I would like to add some changes:

Now :

One characater has multiple equipements, one equipement belongs to multiple characters.

One equipement has multiple stats, one stat belongs to multiple equipements.
[image]

We can know the side of an equipement for a character if we know the caracter and the equipement so I put "side" on the pivot. The problem is : the side only concerns rings so my data for side looks like

```
null | null | null | left | null | right | null |null | null | null
```

**Is it a problem to have an attribute only concerning one type?**

Also, I want to add for a stat, elements. The problem is that for something like 30 stats, only 2 are concerned by elements. And for a stat concerned by an element, the character choose one element or more elements. It will probably looks like this :

[image]

For the moment, I manage the stats like this :

I retrieve all data for a character with his equipements, then when I know his equipements I can retrieve all stats (I know their value through "value_stat"). Thanks to Laravel, I do it with eager loads.

Now to have the "value_stat" I must know id_character, id_equipement, id_stats, id_element because the element chosen depends on the character. Is that pattern correct? Even with that pattern for most of cases, id_element will be set as null because element is only for some stats.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a problem to have an attribute only concerning one type?

Reworded: "Is it OK to have an attribute which will be non-NULL for only a subset of rows?

Answer: Yes. This is common in SQL databases. You just have to make sure that your application handles NULL values correctly.

> Now to have the "value_stat" I must know id_character, id_equipement, id_stats, id_element because the element chosen depends on the character. Is that pattern correct?

Answer: It depends if actual object model is correct! For example, is relation between *equipment* and *stat* really many-to-many? I mean - can one stat record really refer to many different equipments?  If that's the case, no problem. From SQL perspective there is nothing bad about using arbitrary complex relationship model. But from normalization perspective, it must match real world (in this case: game logic).

Comment: Thanks for answering! I understand a bit better. But now, I don't know how to modelise the database to retrieve value of the stat depending on the stat, the character, the equipment and the element. Some stats will be retrieve through "value_stat" because if you know a character, you know equipements. Then you can get all stats.
But what about if the stat has different elements?
If I understood well, I will have to fetch data for "value_stat" then fetch data from my new entity "character_equipement_stat_element"

Comment: @ZeyukanIch' excuse me, it's not clear what you are asking about. I have no idea about your game logic and why do you need character to get equipment stat (equipment can exist without character, right?)...

Comment: Equipement can exist without character. But I must retrieve stats of those equipements. (that's what I'm doing now) Some stats from the equipement can be chose by the character itself... (that's what I'm adding) so I have to know the character, the equipment, the stat and the element. I made a new entity to do that